# SAX Parser, how to dynamically ignore & in input xml file for SAXParser.parse

Tags: java, parsing, sax

I have a scenario where I get an XML from another service and I parse this file and render it to another file.

But, sometimes, we get `&` in the input file inside any tag and when we try to parse this file we get `SAXException`.

Is there a way we can dynamically replace `&`, or we can ignore the `&` sign while parsing?

Comment: What specific exception are you getting? If it actually is invalid xml, then there is no option to "ignore" it.

Comment: XML parsers require *well-formed* XML. You could pre-process your file removing all the `&` (or replacing them with `&amp;` *before* passing it to the SAX parser. If your input is not really XML (e.g. if it's HTML) you should consider using a different parser, such as an HTML parser.

Comment: @helderdarocha: thanks for the quick response. I am now formatting the XML before Parsing and it works like wonders.. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research I have come up with following points:

1. SAX Parser needs a clean XML file without any error, else it will fail and we cannot change characters dynamically in the input. So, we need to check the Input XML file before hand.
2. To change characters in the input file with ease use "StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml" provided by Apache in "org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" package. But, this to has its downside, as it will all the occurences of the character. For reference you can check this blog: "http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-replace-escape-xml-special-characters-java-string.html"
3. But, my use case scenario was different, I need only particular character to be deleted from the input file. So, for that I had to code from scratch; I had to read file and check for the desired character to delete and delete it and write back to the file again.